# How to collect metrics (prometheus ) from Reactive Routes in Quarcus

Tags: java, prometheus, quarkus, metrics, reactive

Quarkus version 3.2.3.Final

I am using reactive routes in quarkus 'io.quarkus:quarkus-reactive-routes'

I am also using promoetheus metrics io.quarkus:quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus.

The problem is that I do not see my endpoints that are annotated with @Route annotation in my metrics.

For example endpoint below:

```
@Route(path = "something", methods = Route.HttpMethod.GET)
public void get(RoutingContext routingContext, @Param(LOGIN_CHALLENGE) @NotBlank(message = LOGIN_CHALLENGE + PARAMETER_SHOULD_BE_SET) String challenge) {
    loginService.get(routingContext, challenge);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should use Reactive routes anymore, because it lacks features and compatibility with other extensions. Switch to reasteasy reactive instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no integrated metrics support for Reactive Routes.
RESTEasy Reactive on the other hand does provide such an integration (as we as others like tracing) and should be used in almost all cases instead of Reactive Routes.

I should also add that RESTEasy Reactive is the stack we are focusing on going forward.